# In Gtk2hs, why do TreeModelIface functions sometimes take an Iter, sometimes a Maybe Iter

Tags: haskell, gtk2hs

In Gtk2hs there is the `Graphics.UI.Gtk.ModelView.CustomStore` module, which includes a data type containing a collection of functions, [`TreeModelIface`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk-0.14.5/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-ModelView-CustomStore.html#t:TreeModelIface). It contains a bunch of functions for navigating around a user-defined tree type where the location is stored as a`TreeIter`. So one of the member functions is:

```
treeModelIfaceIterNext :: TreeIter -> IO (Maybe TreeIter)
```

This returns the `TreeIter` associated with the next sibling node, if there is one. Simple enough. But the following member function is:

```
treeModelIfaceIterChildren :: Maybe TreeIter -> IO (Maybe TreeIter)
```

This takes a `Maybe TreeIter` instead of a simple `TreeIter`. The documentation doesn't say why, or what an argument of `Nothing` is used for.

Questions:

1. Why this variation of argument types?
2. What should `treeModelIfaceIterChilren iface Nothing` return?

Answer (score 2):

It's been sometime since I used the `TreeModelIface` interface, but if I remember correctly, it all has to do with the root (or top-level) nodes of the tree. So `treeModelIfaceIterChilren iface Nothing` is used to retrieve them since they have no parent. This is not an issue when you are iteration over the siblings with `treeModelIfaceIterNext`. In other words, to traverse the entire tree, `treeModelIfaceIterChilren iface Nothing` is your starting point, and the you succesively call `treeModelIfaceIterNext` and `treeModelIfaceIterChilren` (with a `Just` value).